# Могут ли правила в файле .htaccess конфликтовать? нужна помощь.

Tags: .htaccess

Есть два правила в файле .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^shop/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/? php/shop/index.php?url_kategory=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^shop/p-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/? php/shop/index.php?product=$1 [L]
```

могут ли правила конфликтовать в таком случае? Вообще они конфликтуют, прошу подсказать как решить проблему...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второе правило никогда не проверяется.
Поменяйте их местами и все заработает.
Это не конфликт, просто множество совпадений  первого регулярного выражения включает в себя второе, а так как стоит флаг L, то до второго дело не доходит.